# Valid property name checker

Tags: vb.net, t4

I am using vb.net 2010, trying to generate simple classes with properties using T4 from database. Sometimes I get an error that some string is not a valid property name because it is a vb keyword. For example based on database data, my T4 tried to create a class with a property called "property".

Is there a function that check whether a string is a keyword, like:

```
dim a = "property"
if iskeyword(a) then
    a &= "1"
end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @D said, looks like I have to create it myself:

```
Function IsKeyWord(name As String) As Boolean
    Dim keywords As New List(Of String) From {
        "addhandler", "addressof", "alias", "and", "andalso", "as",
        "boolean", "byref", "byte", "byval", "call", "case", "catch", "cbool",
        "cbyte", "cchar", "cdate", "cdec", "cdbl", "char", "cint", "class",
        "clng", "cobj", "const", "continue", "csbyte", "cshort", "csng",
        "cstr", "ctype", "cuint", "culng", "cushort", "date", "decimal",
        "declare", "default", "delegate", "dim", "directcast", "do", "double",
        "each", "else", "elseif", "end", "endif", "enum", "erase", "error",
        "event", "exit", "false", "finally", "for", "friend", "function",
        "get", "gettype", "getxmlnamespace", "global", "gosub", "goto",
        "handles", "if", "implements", "imports", "in", "inherits", "integer",
        "interface", "is", "isnot", "let", "lib", "like", "long", "loop", "me",
        "mod", "module", "mustinherit", "mustoverride", "mybase", "myclass",
        "namespace", "narrowing", "new", "next", "not", "nothing",
        "notinheritable", "notoverridable", "object", "of", "on", "operator",
        "option", "optional", "or", "orelse", "overloads", "overridable",
        "overrides", "paramarray", "partial", "private", "property",
        "protected", "public", "raiseevent", "readonly", "redim", "rem",
        "removehandler", "resume", "return", "sbyte", "select", "set",
        "shadows", "shared", "short", "single", "static", "step", "stop",
        "string", "structure", "sub", "synclock", "then", "throw", "to",
        "true", "try", "trycast", "typeof", "variant", "wend", "uinteger",
        "ulong", "ushort", "using", "when", "while", "widening", "with",
        "withevents", "writeonly", "xor"}
    Return keywords.Contains(name.Trim.ToLower)
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Keywords can be made into valid identifiers in VB by putting them into `[…]`. You could do that for every identifier here, to prevent name clashes. For example the following code compiles:

```
Dim [Dim] As [As] = New [New]()
```

given

```
Class [As]
End Class

Class [New] : Inherits [As]
End Class
```

Comment: Cool! Upvote! Although I will not use this in my code in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Endy You’re right, you shouldn’t. Furthermore, I really hope you find a “real” answer to your orignal question. This is more of a last resort solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on everything I have ever read, keywords are part of the compiler and there is no method you can use to check them built in as they are not exposed.

It would appear in this case you are stuck with using a known list of keywords to build your own check.

Comment: Looks like you are right, but I'm waiting, maybe someone has some trick.

Comment: That would be handy.  I ran in to this a year or so ago myself.